# Data Migration On GCP MemoryStore

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-memorystore

I am working on a project which currently has it's Redis data stored on a managed service called RedisLabs. I read about GCP MemoryStore and found it suitable for my project. So I am trying to move from RedisLabs to GCP MemoryStore.

I have created an Instance on MemoryStore already and now I am looking to migrate our existing Redis data from RedisLabs. In the release notes of MemoryStore, there are mentions of one-click migration, but I could not find any detailed documentation on how to achieve this.

Is there any documentation or tutorial to guide through this? Any kind of help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on supporting RDB persistence. This feature should be available in first half of 2019 (or sooner). We will respond to this thread when we are ready for customers to try this feature in alpha.

Thanks for your patience and trying Memorystore.

-Prajakta (Engineering Manager on Memorystore @GCP)